# Proteger un archivo o directorio con PHPMyAdmin y Apache

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de proteger una carpeta. La carpeta se encuentra en **/var/www/html** y se llama *protegida*. He creado un archivo *.htaccess* dentro de ella con:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Este archivo o directorio está protegido"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Después he creado el archivo *.htpasswd* en **/var/www/** y he ejecutado el comando `htpasswd .htpasswd alex` Y le he puesto una contraseña después.

En la línea final ponía *adding password for user alex*. Y cuando me meto en el archivo *.htpasswd* está la contraseña encriptada.

La cosa es que ahora, desde Google quiero entrar a la carpeta y no me pide ningún tipo de autenticación. ¿Qué hago?

Comment: Cuando dices _desde google quiero entrar a la carpeta_, ¿qué significa? ¿La carpeta aparece indexada cuando buscas tu sitio en el buscador de Google? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade los detalles necesarios. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0):

acuerdate de poner "All" en la configuracion de las opciones de apache
cambiar:

`AllowOverride none` (El uso de ficheros .htaccess puede desactivarse por completo configurando la directiva AllowOverride a none:)

`AllowOverride All` (activas el .htaccess)